# Constant array value as array index don't work in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, class, constants

I define a class field as array constant.
Then I try to use that array field values as an index in another array:

```
class A
{
    const NAMES = Array(
        "A",
    );

    static function run()
    {
        $arr = array("A"=>"123");


        $arNames = constant('self::NAMES');

        foreach ($arNames as $name) {
            echo '$name=' . $name . '<BR>';
            echo '$arr[$name]=' . $arr[$name] . '<BR>';
        }

        $name2=$arNames[0];
        echo '<BR>'.'$name2=' . $name2 . '<BR>';
        echo '$arr[$name2]=' . $arr[$name2] . '<BR>';
    }
}

A::run();
```

On one server under PHP 7.1.23 it works fine and output is :

> ```
> $name=A
> $arr[$name]=123
>
> $name2=A
> $arr[$name2]=123
> ```

But it works wrong on another server whith the same PHP, libs and so on. It sets the **$arr[$name]** to the  **NULL** in the **foreach** loop. But the direct request by numeric index also works fine:

> ```
> $name=A
> $arr[$name]=
>
> $name2=A
> $arr[$name2]=123
> ```

Is there any restriction for using constant arrays? 
I didn't find anything on http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.syntax.php or elsewere.

**Addition**
Now I find out the difference between severs. If **opcode** is enabled, the loop blok works wrong.

Comment: Why do you use `constant` to receive variable? Why not just `static::NAMES` call?

Comment: Theres no difference between recent PHP Versions atleast (as can be seen here https://3v4l.org/9LAI0). Enable proper error reporting on the server where it doesn't work and perform a `diff` on the two files to check for differences.

Comment: That's not my code. I don't know why they used this. I have only migrate the site to PHP 7.1 and discover this mistake on work server. It works fine on test server. My question is about PHP itself, why sometimes it works wrong.
Now I find out the difference between severs. If **opcode** is enabled, the loop blok works wrong.

Comment: Funny. Looks like a bug in opcode for wrong usage of constant() method.